# Python - Stop turtle from leaving canvas

Tags: python, canvas, turtle-graphics

I am making a program using tkinter. I have a canvas and a turtle inside of the canvas. Currently, the turtle moves around the screen using the arrow keys, however I want it to not be able to leave the boundaries of the canvas. Here is my current code

```
canvas = Tk.Canvas(master=self, width=300, height=300)
canvas.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=3, padx=50)

canvas.focus_set()

t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
t.setheading(90)

left_bound = -(canvas.winfo_width() / 2)
right_bound = canvas.winfo_width() / 2
top_bound = canvas.winfo_height() / 2
bottom_bound = -(canvas.winfo_height() / 2)

tx = t.xcor()
ty = t.ycor()

if tx > right_bound or tx < left_bound:
    t.undo()
if ty > top_bound or ty < bottom_bound:
    t.undo()

def move_forward_keys(_):
   t.forward(10)

def move_left_keys(_):
   t.left(20)

def move_right_keys(_):
   t.right(20)

def move_back_keys(_):
   t.back(10)

canvas.bind("<Up>", move_forward_keys)
canvas.bind("<Left>", move_left_keys)
canvas.bind("<Right>", move_right_keys)
canvas.bind("<Down>", move_back_keys)
```

It may be because I am doing something wrong, but this is my code at the moment. Which I think should work because if it leaves, it should undo its last action.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this code:

```
tx = t.xcor()
ty = t.ycor()

if tx > right_bound or tx < left_bound:
    t.undo()
if ty > top_bound or ty < bottom_bound:
    t.undo()
```

is at the top level of your file when it should be embedded in the `move_forward_keys()` and `move_back_keys()` functions:

```
CURSOR_OFFSET = 6  # cursor hotspot closer to front than back

canvas = Tk.Canvas(master=self, width=300, height=300)
canvas.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=3, padx=50)

canvas.focus_set()

t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
t.setheading(90)

left_bound = -(canvas.winfo_width() / 2)
right_bound = canvas.winfo_width() / 2
top_bound = canvas.winfo_height() / 2
bottom_bound = -(canvas.winfo_height() / 2)

def move_forward_keys(_):
    t.forward(9)
    tx, ty = t.position()

    if tx > right_bound or tx < left_bound:
        t.undo()

    if ty > top_bound or ty < bottom_bound:
        t.undo()

def move_left_keys(_):
    t.left(20)

def move_right_keys(_):
    t.right(20)

def move_back_keys(_):
    t.back(9)
    tx, ty = t.position()

    if tx > right_bound - CURSOR_OFFSET or tx < CURSOR_OFFSET + left_bound:
        t.undo()

    if ty > top_bound - CURSOR_OFFSET or ty < CURSOR_OFFSET + bottom_bound:
        t.undo()

canvas.bind("<Up>", move_forward_keys)
canvas.bind("<Left>", move_left_keys)
canvas.bind("<Right>", move_right_keys)
canvas.bind("<Down>", move_back_keys)
```